# How to set rsp in gdb while examining a coredump?

Tags: gdb

I was trying to set rsp so that I can see call stack from it:

```
(gdb) p $rsp
$1 = (void *) 0xd995f4be70
(gdb) set $rsp=0xd986f9c0
You can't do that without a process to debug.
```

My question is how to set rsp and other registers in gdb coredump?

I'm using gdb-7.10

Comment: Maybe [`frame view 0xd986f9c0`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Selection.html#index-frame-view-553) works?

Comment: This can work, but I want to change all registers to change current frame to another frame that I want. Is there any solution? Please.

Comment: No, as the error message says, you can't change any registers from a coredump.